# Firebase Cloud messaging login management

Tags: android, firebase-cloud-messaging

Basically, i want that every time that the user logs in, to:

- Request a firebase token;
- Register the token in my webserver;
- Put the MessagingService running;

When the user logs out:

- The message service must stop;
- Token unregistered from my webserver;

The main problem that i am facing are:

- Firebase detects that a token doesn't exist and it requests a new token even if the user is not logged.
- FirebaseMessageService responsible to listen to messages starts to run automatically when the token is received;

Answer (score 1):

Instead of trying to prevent the token from being created/registered, how about implementing the two requirements as two separate pieces of data:

1. the user's FCM token
2. whether the user is signed in

That way you remove the complex condition from your app code and instead have a very simple condition at the server"

```
if (user.signed_in && user.token != null) {
    sendMessageTo(user);
}
```

Comment: But this way, the service listening to messages would keep running anyway, and this is one of the point of this questions, Frank. I want to stop it in some cases, like if the user in the preferences screen chooses to disable push notifications, or the user decides to walk around the app not being logged.

Comment: How about having a topic for the opt-in? You'd essentially tie the checkbox to subscribing to/unsubscribing from the topic.

Comment: Note: Even though the token is auto generated you are under no obligation to use it, till the user is logged in. Also the FirebaseMessagingService is not started once the token is generated. It is started by Google Play Services when necessary, like when a message comes in.

Comment: That sounds like it might actually make a great alternative answer @ArthurThompson. I'd upvote it! :-)

Answer (score 0):

In addition to @FrankvanPuffelen's answer note that even though the token is auto generated you are under no obligation to use it, till the user is logged in. Also the FirebaseMessagingService is not started once the token is generated. It is started by Google Play services when necessary, like when a message comes in.